# Access Report Prompts for query twice

Tags: ms-access, querying

I am developing a report that has a text portion and a graphical portion. Both portions of the report are created using the same query. Unfortunately, I am being prompted twice when running the report and then a third time if I want to print it. When the query runs, it uses the criteria [Enter ID number:] for one of the fields.

How can I change the report to only prompt one time? I'd be happy to supply additional information if needed.

Answer (score 1):

For the most part, it is best to use a small form to provide parameters for reports. You get better control and can prompt the user, and parameters need only be entered once.